# how to add nth element from char array to arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays

just trying to add the nth element from a char array to an Array list. However, I will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to run my following method. I am guessing it is because of my x[i+2] doesn't work when the array reaches its end?

Here's my code for my method:

```
public void Encode (char[] x){
    for(int i = 3; i < x.length; i++) {

        mid.add(x[i+1]);
        bottom.add(x[i+2]);
        top.add(x[i]);
        top.removeAll(mid);
        top.removeAll(bottom);
    }
} 

 public ArrayList getTop(){
    return top;
}

public ArrayList getMid() {
    return mid;
}

public ArrayList getBottom() {
    return bottom;
}
```

}

Comment: As your loop start from 3, so it is logical to have `[x-1]` and `[x-2]` instead of `[x+1]` and `[x+2]`

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the array index, to use `x[i+2]` you need to constrain `i` to `x.length-2`. That is

```
for(int i = 3; i < x.length - 2; i++) {
```

when i = x.length - 2 then +2 is x.length (and out of bounds).

Comment: yeah I suspected thats whats causing me the error. if you don't mind can you tell me what method should I use to store every nth element from my char array to my arraylist?

Comment: Change `i++` to `i+=n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mid.add(x[i+1]); is  throwing exception.
```

Your size of Array must always be greater by index+1 than the index you are extracting from the array.

You should use something like

```
public void Encode (char[] x){
        for(int i = 3; i < x.length; i++) {


            int size=x.length-1;


            if (size>(i+1)) {
                 mid.add(x[i+1]);
            }

            if (size>(i+2)) {
                 bottom.add(x[i+2]);
            }
            if (size>i) {
                 top.add(x[i]);
            }


            top.removeAll(mid);
            top.removeAll(bottom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Calling `mid.add(x[i+1]);` does not select which index in the `ArrayList` to add the value to. By the way, that is possible to do. However, that is not the problem. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown because of `x[i+1]`, because `i+1` is greater than `x.length`.

Comment: I guess you mean *Array*, because *ArrayList* is very different. If you mean *ArrayList*, read my commend above.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 It was left over statement for my last edit. Thank for correcting though.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown because of `x[i+2]`, because `i+2` is greater than `x.length`.

You could check if the index is valid each iteration, before using it.

Out of curiosity, what is the function going to encode?